# Byte array getString only converts the first index

Tags: c#, arrays, sockets, unity-game-engine, byte

I am attempting to send data across localhost via TCP, the data is being sent and put into a byte array, then converted to a string and finally printed out. Everything except the converting to a string works:
Data is appearing in Wireshark
The byte array holds all the correct bytes

However, when printing I only see the first index.

```
bytes = new byte[1024];
int bytesRec = handler.Receive(bytes, 0, handler.Available, SocketFlags.None);

data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec);
Debug.Log(data);
```

Message being shown in Wireshark:

[image: Wireshark]

Comment: According [to the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kzb9f993(v=vs.110).aspx), `bytesRec` is a count of the number of bytes you want to convert to string. What is the value of `bytesRec`? Is the second character in the buffer `'\0'`? What do you mean by "only see the first index": Do you mean the first character?

Comment: What is `handler`? Is `Receive()` your own implementation of `Stream.Read()`?

Comment: You have non printable characters in the data.  The ones that show up as periods in wireshark.  The printer is probably seeing some of these characters as control characters which may cause the printer to stop printing.

Comment: So the problem was the non printable characters, cheers.